# JavaScript How Can I convert this innerText to a valid date format?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to use the new Date() object in FireFox. I'm pulling the date using this code:

`var createDate = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date').innerText;`

Which returns the following:

```
var createDate = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date').innerText;
createDate
"2021-08-19 08:20:53 AM"
```

But when I try and create a new Date object using the following code, I get an Invalid Date error.

```
var newDate = new Date(createDate);
newDate
Invalid Date
```

How can I make `createDate` be a valid Date?

Comment: You'll need to format it correctly for `new Date` to accept, or use a library which does it for you.

Comment: What would be the easiest way to convert it to a format that `new Date` would accept?

Comment: Remove the `' AM'` from the date string. There are multiple ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting date for `new Date()`

```js
var createDate = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date').innerText;
console.log(createDate)
createDate = createDate.split(" ");

var newDate = new Date(createDate[0]+"T"+createDate[1])
console.log(newDate)
```

```html
<div class="formatted-absolute-date">2021-08-19 08:20:53 AM</div>
```

Comment: Note that if the date is `2021-08-19 08:20:53 PM` you convert it to `2021-08-19T08:20:53` and not `2021-08-19T20:20:53`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both Harshit, & 3limin4t0r by adding the `if` statement, I can get it to work as I need it to.

```js
var createDate1 = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date1').innerText;
var createDatePM1 = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date1').innerText.substr(20, 2);
console.log(createDate1);

var newCreateDate1 = createDate1.split(' ');
var ecd1 = new Date(newCreateDate1[0]+'T'+ newCreateDate1[1]);

if (createDatePM1 == 'PM') {
  ecd1 = new Date(ecd1.valueOf() + 43200000)
}
console.log(ecd1);

var createDate2 = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date2').innerText;
var createDatePM2 = document.querySelector('.formatted-absolute-date2').innerText.substr(20, 2);
console.log(createDate2);

var newCreateDate2 = createDate2.split(' ');
var ecd2 = new Date(newCreateDate2[0]+'T'+ newCreateDate2[1]);

if (createDatePM2 == 'PM') {
  ecd2 = new Date(ecd2.valueOf() + 43200000)
}
console.log(ecd2);
```

```html
<div class="formatted-absolute-date1">2021-09-02 06:24:39 AM</div>
<div class="formatted-absolute-date2">2021-09-02 06:24:39 PM</div>
```

Comment: Fails with '2021-09-02 12:24:39 AM" because the hour is parsed as 12, not 0. Also, `2021-09-02 06:24:39 PM` fails because the hour is parsed as 12, then 12 more hours are added. You have to parse the time separately and adjust the hour based on am/pm. Best to just split it into parts and call the Date constructor with the adjusted values.

Comment: Consider `function myParse(str) { let [Y,M,D,H,m,s,ap] = str.split(/\W/);  H = H % 12 + (ap.toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12);  return new Date(Y,M-1,D,H,m,s);}`. :-)

Comment: Thanks RobG. Using your method works.